# How to export interface with CHICKEN Scheme?

Tags: chicken-scheme

The documentation is not clear on how to use an interface from one unit into another.

I have the following unit *a.scm*:

```lisp
(declare (unit a))

(define-interface polite
  (say-hello))
```

and the following unit *b.scm*:

```lisp
(declare (uses a))

(module foo (interface: polite) ...)
```

When building *b.scm*, *csc* complains about knowing about `polite`:

```
Warning: reference to possibly unbound identifier `polite'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I don't know whether it's the best way to do it, but I put my interface into its own file that I include every time I need it. So in my case it's:

In polite.scm:

```
(define-interface polite
  (say-hello))
```

In b.scm:

```
(declare (unit b))
(include "polite.scm")

(module foo (interface: polite) ...)
```